# How to fetch key value from local storage and show in an HTML view in angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage

I want to fetch a key value from local storage and bind this value in HTML view. How can I do this in angular 2?

Answer (score 1):

**DEMO : https://plnkr.co/edit/iiumw4NWPPIRqG0zLBYP?p=preview**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <button (click)="click()">Get Value</button>
  {{lastname}}`
})
export class AppComponent {
     constructor(){
        localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
     }

    click(){
        this.lastname=localStorage.getItem("lastname");
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather assigning localStorage value to a variable and using in HTML, can we directly get localStorage data in HTML like `{{localStorage.getItem("lastname")}}`

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Download the library using npm or github: `npm install --save angular2-localstorage`

Step 2: Import it and add it to bootstrap()

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [OtherProvider, LocalStorage]);
```

Step 3: use it in your controller

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <button (click)="click()">Set Value</button>
  <button (otherClickHandler)="click()">Get Value</button>
  {{localVar}}`
})
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(private ls:LocalStorage) {}

  clickHandler() {
    this.ls.set('someKey', 'someValue');
  }
  otherClickHandler() {
    this.localVar = ls.get('someKey'); 
  }
}
```